# What is my server name SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I believe it is a full license install. I have tried my computer name\SQLEXPRESS and SQL2012. It is a new install. I've also tried looking at the SQL server configuration manager.

[image: SQL Server]

[image: Config Manager]

Comment: You have no service with Type 'Sql Server'

Comment: Try `.`. Otherwise, use `services.msc` to verify you have an SQL Server service running at all, as it doesn't look that way from the configuration manager.

Comment: The only SQL service I have under services is SQL Server Integration Services 11.0 and it is not started. Do I need another part of SQL Server Management Studio installed? If so what is it called?

Comment: You don't have SQL Server installed, period. Management Studio is just a front-end tool to manage SQL Server, and it is evidently installed. Run setup again and make sure to select the database engine.

Comment: SSMS is an IDE. SQL Server is a database management system. They are not the same thing at all. And SQL Server Integration Services is something different as well, neither an IDE nor database, but a service that runs automated SQL processes (this is what you have installed).

Comment: Go back to the guy who installed only SQL Server Integration Services tell him to please install the database engine now.